# I cannot understand the code that i found online

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a question, i found this script for sticky navigation on internet and i don't understand why the line 'var Scroll Y = $(window). scrollTop();' can't be over 'var stickyNav = function(){'

Thanks for help  :)

```
 <script>

 $(document).ready(function() {
       var NavY = $('.nav').offset().top;

       var stickyNav = function(){
       var ScrollY = $(window).scrollTop();

       if (ScrollY > NavY) { 
           $('.nav').addClass('sticky');
       } else {
           $('.nav').removeClass('sticky'); 
       }
   };

    stickyNav();

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        stickyNav();
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: Because it has to get the actual position during scroll happens

Comment: Because moving a line of code from inside a function to outside a function (or the other way around) changes the structure of what the code does.  Basically, when you modify code, the code becomes *different*.

Comment: Yes, the `stickyNav()` function executes on scroll, so the current scroll position from top needs to be determined dynamically at the point at which scroll is triggered.  Data cached from before this point is redundant.

Comment: I would be slightly apprehensive to use code from that author, because they 1) don't follow common naming conventions for variables, and 2) they don't understand how to use function references. It should be `$(window).scroll(stickyNav);`

Comment: Note: If you apply consistent indentation to the code it will be a lot easier to understand its structure.

Answer (score 0):

`ScrollY` is calculated as the distance from the top of the `$(window)` object, so it needs to be re-calculated every time the user scrolls as it's not a constant variable set at the start, unlike `NavY` which is the distance between the nav and the top of the window.

This is done as the function `stickyNav()` is called whenever the user starts scrolling within the `.scroll()` event.